# SweetAlert with React not updating value in input field in a form in a jsx file

Tags: react-redux, jsx, sweetalert

First of all I've to say this is my first time touching react code, so my problem may be a noob one, tried several things, but really don't know what else to do.
I'm using [SweetAlert](https://github.com/djorg83/react-bootstrap-sweetalert). You can see some examples [here](https://djorg83.github.io/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/). On a jsx file.

And I've the following code.

```
handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target; //e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });

    console.log("HandleChange: ",e);
    console.log("Target: ",e.target);
    console.log("name: ",name);
    console.log("value: ",value);
}

const editAnswer =(index) => {
    this.setState({
        editAnswerPopup: (
            <SweetAlert
                showCancel
                title={"Edit Answer"}
                onConfirm={() => saveAnswer()}
                onCancel={() => cancelAnswer()}
                type={'controlled'}
                dependencies={[this.state.changeText, this.state.changeValue]}
            >
                <form>
                    <h5>{index}</h5>
                    {AnswerValueValidationError()}
                    {AnswerTextLenghtValidationError()}
                    <input
                        id="changeText"
                        name="changeText"
                        type={'text'}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.changeText}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        placeholder={'Text'}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <input
                        id="changeValue"
                        name="changeValue"
                        type={'number'}
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.changeValue}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        placeholder={'Value'}
                    />
                </form>
            </SweetAlert>
        )
    });
}
```

And when I press any key inside one of the input fields, the handleChange event captures the change ok, showing me in the console what is suposed to be the new value (The current value plus the key pressed), but it's not reflected in the input that acts like it would be locked (or that I would have certain validation that doesn't let it change.
The handleChange event is called by several other input fields fields and they act normally as they should. The only difference with these ones, is that the form is inside a Sweetalert, and that the component is not added to the state/DOM until I click in a particular button to edit something, unlike the others that are presented when the page loads.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
The code was partially taken from the last example of [SweetAlert](https://djorg83.github.io/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/). The difference is that the example has some extra code to be used in a ts file, and I'm using a jsx. But for what I understood of React, my code should work. But it doesn't so I guess, I'm missimng something.

Comment: Why are you setting the value attribute of the fields on every keypress via a state change? The value attribute for an <input> element in HTML is used to specify the *initial* value of the input element.

Comment: This is not something I developed from scratch, but something I'm modifing. Anyway, in the  handleChange() function also has some validations (I didn't write in the code example) to show on the fly alerts when wrong values are typed.

Comment: Also, guess this is the way React-Redux-jsx works, if I remove the onChange it continues to do nothing.

Comment: This might help you, [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I was setting a state of a property (changeText) inside another property of a state (editAnswerPopup).